# Codeigniter htaccess redirect to controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hellow i'm trying to redirect the user to a specific controller if someone uses get_file_contents on my website.

Here is my code

```
----------
# Options
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks

#Enable mod rewrite
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /codeigniter/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(java|curl|wget).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(winhttp|HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner|curl|wget|python|nikto|scan).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# Here im trying to go to index.php/hacks controller
# it always goes to default controller set in config
# i want to go to a specific controller
# how can i do this ?
```

Comment: I had to read the code to know what the question is

Answer (score 0):

For most of the cases, you can control redirects in `application/config/routes.php`

For example, if you want to redirect a user who requests `http://mysite.com/page` to `http://mysite.com/page2` you will add in there:

```
$route['page'] = "page2";
```

To change the controller you want to be called when the site is loaded with no data, you will have to change the default controller:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "hacks"
```

Comment: i want the default_controller be the default controller

Comment: i want to use something like

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/hacks/$1 [L]

Comment: i have this in my routes $route['hacks'] = "hacks";

Comment: it doesn't work and i hate this, im blocked on this for 3 days, i didn't have any choise only to put my script on stackoverflow :D

Comment: If you need to redirect all of your requests to a specific controller, why not just set it in `index.php`?

Comment: how, and where in index.php ?? :)

Comment: There's directive called _DEFAULT CONTROLLER_ which allows you to set only one controller for the whole application (basically what you want to achieve, from what I've understood so far). It is on line 79 in the `index.php` file in the root folder.